# Twitter Bootstrap: What would be the best way to add a background color to the side margins but not the main content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make it so that the content in the center remains with a white a background but the side margins are a different color. What would be the best way to accomplish this with TBS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the background color to `body {}` and put `.container` as `background-color:#fff`.

That assumes you're using `.container` as your main container class.

Comment: The issue here is that container has no padding around the content and also does not go all the way to the bottom of the page. What would be a way around this? Thanks!

Comment: You could put a background image on `body` with a white section in the middle and color on the sides at the appropriate size to give the illusion of padding. You'd need several different versions of this and several media queries if you're going responsive, but it's the easiest way. Modifying the padding on `.content` is harder that it seems it should be with Bootstrap's grid.